# Cache Memory space/allocation in Mobile Devices

Tags: database, cordova, caching, maps, mobile-devices

However, I think I'm right to assume that any device's cache memory is dependent on the device. So my first question is

Is the available cache memory dependent on the device's memory OR do—specifically iOS, Android, and Window—application's allocate space natively for each application?

I would assume it is and always depended on the device. The reason I ask is I've been attempting to implement a fully offline static Mapbox map for a small town in a Phonegap application and I see so many examples of storing the map in the cache calming to be "offline", if the cache memory is dependent on the device cache memory this wouldn't be the case unless the application allocated space, and holds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching is done through the browser (in hybrid apps) so its decided by the app.